# Jquery breaks down the rest of my javascript/jquery code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am wondering why my jquery code breaks down the rest of my javascript/jquery code.
In the head i use:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Then the custom.js file is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $('.sidebar-box', '#sidebar').min-height($('#content', '#main').height());
});
```

Comment: Where have you seen `min-height` method?

Comment: Try `jQuery(function($){ code here})`. We basically just namespace the `$` variable to that specific `ready function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min-height` is not a jQuery method. You probably meant:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.sidebar-box', '#sidebar').css('min-height',$('#content', '#main').height());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: Thanks. The min-height jquery did work but was not the correct way to code it i guess.. Thanks a lot.. this helped me out!

Answer (score 3):

probably because jQuery has no `.min-height()` method? I'm assuming it should be:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.sidebar-box', '#sidebar').css('min-height', $('#content', '#main').height());
});
```

Note that Wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default, and requires a no-conflict wrapper, and you should include scripts with `wp_enque_script`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am familiar with the wp_enque_script function. Thanks again!